# Django - hide button if condition is true

Tags: javascript, python, django, if-statement

Please help me solve a question! I'm using Django.
I have a page where I listed all the questionnaires I made. Every questionnaires has a button next to it that links to a questionnaire on my main site.

I like to make every questionnaires to can be filled just one time to every authenticated user but I can't figure out what is the best way to do this.

Now I think that I create a hidden field into every questionnaires with a `TRUE` value and when the user clicks the submit button it stores in the db with the other answers. I query and retrieve the value and grab it with Javascript. If the value is `TRUE` it hides the button on the main site so it can't be clickable.

Is this solutions good or it can be made easier?

Comment: Show some code. Best way would be not showing/loading questions a user answered once again. Like in your views where you define a queryset, exclude the once which have been answered...

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer. I can share my code but it doesn't contain any from that I asked because I'm just planning the way I could solve the problem.